# Resizing markers given traffic data on Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm not an experienced programmer at all so pardon me if I use some terms wrong.

Currently creating a map on train crossings, number of trains per day, and the daily traffic that goes thru those crossings. I have them all laid out in 5 separate fusion tables (100+ trains, 80-99, 60-79, 40-59, under 40 trains), and have a different colour marker for each category.

I'm trying to find a way to have the markers change in size given the traffic data going thru the crossings, and haven't figured out how to do that. I've laid out the sizes I want for the circles given traffic data, but don't know how to incorporate it in the markers themselves.

Here's the jsfiddle and some of the coding I have. Since I was in a rush I copied everything into the javascript section, but there's some CSS and HTML stuff in the coding too. Currently the coding properly shows the map, legend, and where all the crossings are.

Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/jdg9zz0y/

```
  var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(style, {
    map: map,
    name: 'Styled Map'
  });
  map.mapTypes.set('map-style', styledMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('map-style');

 <!-- 100+ layer -->
var layer_CandidateCrossingO100 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer ({      
    query: {
    select: "col1",
    from: "1DMatlMkpGhAkaAhPx_6sjXW_CGzN71P92tzbvoNk",
    },
    map: map,
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  });  

  <!-- 80 to 99 layer -->
var layer_CandidateCrossing80to99 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
    select: "col1",
    from: "11gfA9J0jlRQyvhXiRxvZD90ApIonAveGfOGW5bGG",
    },
    map: map,
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  });

  <!-- 60 to 79 layer -->
var layer_CandidateCrossing60to79 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
    select: "col1",
    from: "1fth-vFws0sfpfd0SDn1PHow9WMlyGuImClxpYpiG",
    },
    map: map,
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  });

  <!-- 40 to 59 layer -->
var layer_CandidateCrossing40to59 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
    select: "col1",
    from: "168C1S6zxRyWqnDxriSnaF36EnMV17S1wPjrXf9hz",
    },
    map: map,
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  });

<!-- Under 40 layer -->
var layer_CandidateCrossingU40 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({    
    query: {
    select: "col1",
    from: "1mm9ZoqTVQH1LPDhUPM8PQ3ydHooRfxBtvvv8UOgs",
    },
    map: map,
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  });
```

Comment: That fiddle doesn't seem to displaying the map properly. I'd take the time to get the example working right to get a good answer.

Comment: Weird...the fiddle isn't working, but when I copy/paste into notepad and save it as html, it runs fine.

Comment: It probably has to do with everything being in the JavaScript field instead of just HTML in the HTML field and just JS in the JS field. I know that jsfiddle has to load external resources (like the google maps js api) through the External Resources button on the left, so that could also be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

While you create the marker, you can specify the icon. But it is possible through the bees to create the icon object as well, so you can choose the size

Below the example

```
var image = {
  url: place.icon,
  size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    title: place.name,
    position: place.geometry.location
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves half my problem. How do I apply the scaled sizes into the traffic data? I assume it's something to do with the fusion table maps.

Comment: Should note I have something like this right now https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-simple via fusion tables, but would want to scale the markers according to traffic data.